# cant see any json when loading json page

Tags: php, json

I am trying to make a startup api for testing. i have most of the work done but now when i try to load up my page it doesnt show any json just `[]` although my db clearly has some stuff in it.
Like:
Thing| Place | Time
Test | Test  | Test

here is my code:

```
<?php
//Converting db values into json data

header('Content-type:application/json');

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','snippets') or die(mysql_error());
$sql= 'SELECT * FROM wtd';
$rs=$conn->query($sql);

$data = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);


?>
```

Hope someone can help me. Im on a time limit

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara it prints this []Array()

Comment: is the blank password deliberate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to add some error processing to your code, the error could be anywhere but you are not actually looking for any apart from on connection where you are using a totally different extension to process the possible error. That wont work!

```
<?php
// force some error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Converting db values into json data

header('Content-type:application/json');

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','snippets');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $conn->connect_errno . ') '
            . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql= 'SELECT * FROM wtd';
$rs=$conn->query($sql);
if ( ! $rs ) {
    echo 'Error in query '.$rs->error;
}

$data = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if ( is_array($data) ) {

    $json = json_encode($data);
    if ( json_last_error() > 0 ) {
        echo json_last_error_msg();
    } else {
        echo $json;
    }
} else {
    echo 'fetch_all failed';
}
exit;
?>
```

Comment: btw: the $conn object has been misnamed as $con in a couple of places

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 24

Comment: thats the if ( is_array($data) {

Comment: Yup fixed it try again

Comment: i have switched from mysql server so i need to create the database again. i'll give youthe result in the end of the day at around 7 PM UTC +01:00

Comment: IT WORKED THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following to see if anything happens - the blank password worries me!

```
/* Blank password? Really? And it should be mysqli_error() */
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','snippets') or die( mysqli_error() );

if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    printf("Connection to database failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$sql= 'select * from `wtd`;';
$rs=$conn->query( $sql );

$data = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$conn=null;

echo json_encode( $data );
```

Comment: Thaks i will try! And the reason that there is no password is that xampp doesnt have an localhost/intsall page anymore

Comment: so the db does not have a password? Otherwise it is essentially the same code but when I tried this without a password and no debug it failed with and no error was displayed. After putting the `if(mysqli_connect_errno() ) {` code in I could immediately see the problem was the password

Comment: Password is not necessary, its bad practice but not necessary